# Как в Laravel изменить шаблон Email письма (регистрация, сброс пароля)?

Tags: laravel

подскажите пожалуйста как в laravel 5.8 изменить HTML шаблон E-Mail письма отправляемое после регистрации/сбросе пароля? Спасибо.

Comment: А разве там с коробки отправка есть?

Comment: из под коробки уже есть реализация

Comment: Так найдите темплейт и смените, в чем проблема?

Comment: Опубликуйте его `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail` и он появиться в папке представлений `vendor/mail` только это базовый шаблон для всех писем

Answer (score 0):

Можно опубликовать шаблон командой `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`, после чего он появится в resources/vendor и отредактировать его.

Answer (score -1):

Есть вариант самому написать сервис и реализовать шаблон:

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class EmailService extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    private $login;
    private $pass;

    public function __construct($login, $pass) {
      $this->login = $login;
      $this->pass = $pass;
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from(env('EMAIL_FROM'))
            ->subject('ТЕМА ПИСЬМА')
            ->view('mail', ['login' => $this->login,  'pass' => $this->pass]) //шаблон письма resources/view/mail.blade
    }
}
```

в папке resources/view/mail.blade можно реализовать сам темплейт

Вызов сервиса:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
...
private function sendMail() {
   Mail::to($this->email)->send(new EmailService($this->login, $this->pass));
   return (['data' => 'success']);
     
}
```